# Absorbing Markov chain arithmetic multiplicity of eigenvalue 1

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, stochastic-processes, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, markov-chains

Im trying to demostrate that:

**Theorem** In an Absorbent Markov chain, the eigenvalue $\lambda = 1$ has a arithmetic multiplicity equal to the number of absorbent states (columns such that $m_{ii} = 1$) and all the others eigenvalues are  $| \lambda | < 1$.

But all my tries were futile.

Comment: An absorbing vector is a vector $v$ such that $Av = v$, which is exactly the same as an eigenvector with eigenvalue $1$. So certainly the dimension of the $1$-eigenspace is precisely the number of absorbing states.

Comment: Yes, but I was trying to demostrate this using math. Also, I don't how explain that the others eigenvalues are $\|lamba| < 1$